# Working regex not work in laravel validation

Tags: regex, laravel, validation

I have custom regex for validation user profile url in social sites:

```
/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:ok|odnoklassniki)\.ru\/(?:\w*#!\/)?([\w-]*)/
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/BCbmEw/4).

**Code:**

```
if(isset($request->odnoklassniki)) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'odnoklassniki' => 'regex:/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:ok|odnoklassniki)\.ru\/(?:\w*#!\/)?([\w-]*)?/'
    ], ['regex' => 'Enter correct url to your profile in this website']);
    $candidate->odnoklassniki = $request->odnoklassniki;
    $candidate->save(); 
}
```

**Error message:**

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Regex work successfully in my **php code**:

```
$re = '/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:ok|odnoklassniki)\.ru\/(?:\w*#!\/)?([\w-]*)/m';
$str = 'https://www.odnoklassniki.ru/username

http://odnoklassniki.ru/username

ok.ru/username
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.odnoklassniki.ru/username
            [1] => username
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://odnoklassniki.ru/username
            [1] => username
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ok.ru/username
            [1] => username
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe character "**|**" has special function in the validation, it separates your validation rules, e.g.:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255'
]);
```

But since your regex validation includes the pipe character, you can use the other method of declaring validation rules

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => [
        'required',
        'unique:posts',
        'max:255'
    ]
]);
```

So this is the solution to your problem:

```
if(isset($request->odnoklassniki)) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'odnoklassniki' => [
            'regex:/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:ok|odnoklassniki)\.ru\/(?:\w*#!\/)?([\w-]*)?/'
        ]
    ], ['regex' => 'Enter correct url to your profile in this website']);
    $candidate->odnoklassniki = $request->odnoklassniki;
    $candidate->save(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @aceraven777